# How can I reference a class from a specific documentation with Intersphinx?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I have set up an [Intersphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/intersphinx.html)-mapping for the documentations of Python 2 and Python 3:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'py2': ('http://docs.python.org/', None),
                       'py3': ('http://docs.python.org/3', None)}
```

How can I reference a class from a specific of these two resources? The documentation only mentions `:ref:`erences and these two attempts do not work:

```
:ref:`collections.Mapping <py2:collections.Mapping>`
:class:`py3:collections.Mapping`
```

While this generates an expected link:

```
:class:`collections.Mapping`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup below produces working links with your `intersphinx_mapping` configuration (for `py2`, I suggest changing the URL to `http://docs.python.org/2` to make the version explicit).

Python 2:

```
:class:`py2:collections.Mapping`
```

Python 3 (`Mapping` was moved to `collections.abc` in Python 3.3):

```
:class:`py3:collections.abc.Mapping`
```